# How to gather dynamic svn revision numbers in powershell?

Tags: powershell-3.0

I want to declare a dynamic svn revision so that when I call my function I will be able to get first revision and last revision irregardless of time. So far I can only specify the revision number which I dont want to do anymore

Here is my code:

$FromRev = "100"
    $Torev = "200"

```
$Range = $FromRev + ':' + $ToRev

$NewTable = "SVNStaticTable"
#Create Table object
$table = New-Object system.Data.DataTable “$NewTable”

#Define Columns
$col1 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn Author,([string])
$col2 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn Revision,([string])
$col3 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn Msg,([string])
$col4 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn Path,([string])
#$col5 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn Comment,([string])

#Add the Columns
$table.columns.add($col1)
$table.columns.add($col2)
$table.columns.add($col3)
$table.columns.add($col4)
#$table.columns.add($col5)

$LogOutput = ([xml](svn log http://server/folder1/folder2 -v -r $Range --xml)).log.logentry
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($entry in $LogOutput) {
        $Paths = $entry.paths.path 
        Foreach ($path in $paths) {
            if ($path.InnerText -like "*/static/*"){
                #Create a row
                $row = $table.NewRow()
                $row.Author = $entry.author
                $row.Revision = $entry.revision
               # $row.Msg = $entry.msg.Replace('\D+(\d+)\D+','$1') #you call a function here
                #$row.Msg = $entry.msg.Replace("\w", '') #you call a function here
                #$row.Msg = $entry.msg.Substring(0,7 ) #using the substring works
                $row.Msg = $entry.msg
                #$row.Msg = $test -replace "^.*_(\d*)$test.*$", '$1'
                $row.Path = $path.InnerText.Replace("/branches/R3.21/db/static/","")
                #$row.Path = $path.Replace('\..*')
                #$row.Comment = $entry.Comment
                $table.Rows.Add($row)
            }
        }
   }
```